# How to check monetized and non-monetized videos from my YouTube channel

Tags: youtube

I have created a YouTube channel with CC-Licenced content. How can I see if my video is monetized and whether any ads are displayed?

Answer (score 1):

You can see, which of your videos are monetized by dollar icons in your "Video Manager" page

[image: Video Manager]

- Green icon — Video is monetized
- Dollar icon — Video is not monetized , but can be
- Crossed dollar icon — Video is not monetized , and can't be.

Enable monetization, and choose types of ads you want via video editing page in tab "Monetization":

[image: Monetization]