# If a YouTube video is monetized, how can I see if the revenue goes to the channel’s owner, YouTube or a 3rd-party, if I'm not the video/channel owner?

Tags: youtube

I know that:

1. One [can](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/95855/18147) see if a video on YouTube is monetized if one is the video/channel owner.
2. One [can](https://redd.it/uw1i05) see if a YouTube channel is monetized even if one is not the channel owner:

   > When you're on view page source [of the YouTube channel], hit CTRL+F to open the search box and search the value "**is_monetization_enabled**".
   >
   > If you can read
   > "key":"is_monetization_enabled","value":"**true**".
   > then the channel is monetized.
   >
   > If you can read
   > "key":"is_monetization_enabled","value":"**false**".
   > then the channel is NOT monetized.
3. One [can](https://isthischannelmonetized.com/#:%7E:text=its%20monetization%20status.-,How%20To%20Check%20If%20A%20Youtube%20Video%20Is%20Monetized,is%20monetized%2C%20else%20it%27s%20not.) see if a video on YouTube is monetized, even if one is not the video/channel owner:

   > To check if a video is monetized, go to the video's page, view the page's source code, and search for the string `yt_ad`. If the string is present and set to true, the video is monetized, else it's not.

[isthischannelmonetized.com](https://isthischannelmonetized.com/#:%7E:text=Now%2C%20seeing%20ads,videos%20or%20channels) mentions:

> Seeing ads on a video or seeing the “yt_ad” string in the page source code doesn’t mean that the video is monetized by the channel’s owner – it could be monetized by YouTube itself or by a third-party.

If a YouTube video is monetized, how can I see if the revenue goes to the channel’s owner, YouTube or a 3rd-party, if I'm not the video/channel owner?